# Kivy change color of Widget at runtime

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have the following widget:

```
class WhiteKey(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WhiteKey, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.col = (1,1,1,1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*self.col)
            Rectangle(pos=kwargs.get("pos"),size=(23,150))
```

And I add a couple of them to a list, which I then draw on the canvas:

```
class Piano(Widget):
    keys = list()
    for i in range(7):
            self.keys.append(WhiteKey())

    for key in self.keys:
            self.canvas.add(key.canvas)
```

Now I want to change the color of a specific key but when I do something like `self.keys[i].col = (0.5,0.5,0.5,1)` nothing changes. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Full code (EDIT: made the code a bit clearer and fixed a bug):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

from random import random

class WhiteKey(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WhiteKey, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.color = (1,1,1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*self.color)
            Rectangle(pos=kwargs.get("pos"),size=(23,150))

class Piano(Widget):
    keys = list()
    def setupPiano(self):
        for i in range(7):
            self.keys.append(WhiteKey(pos=(24*i,0)))

        for key in self.keys:
                self.canvas.add(key.canvas)


    def update(self, dt):
        self.keys[0].color = (random(), 1, 1)

        self.canvas.clear()
        print(self.keys[0].color)

        for key in self.keys:
                self.canvas.add(key.canvas)


class PianoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Piano()
        game.setupPiano()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PianoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a pretty dumb mistake, I had to pipe the update through to make sure the key itself was updating.

The following code works:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

from random import random

class WhiteKey(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WhiteKey, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.color = (1,1,1)
        self.pos = kwargs.get("pos")
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*self.color)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos,size=(23,150))
    def update(self):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*self.color)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos,size=(23,150))

class Piano(Widget):
    keys = list()
    def setupPiano(self):
        for i in range(7):
            self.keys.append(WhiteKey(pos=(24*i,0)))

        for key in self.keys:
                self.canvas.add(key.canvas)


    def update(self, dt):
        self.keys[0].color = (random(), 1, 1)
        print(self.keys[0].color)

        for key in self.keys:
                key.update()


class PianoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Piano()
        game.setupPiano()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PianoApp().run()
```